# Можно ли в PHP curl получить информацию о таймингах загрузки страницы/файла аналогичную браузеру?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, тайминги

Для отладки одного из API не мешало бы получить информацию о таймингах загрузки страницы аналогичную той что можно посмотреть в браузерах если нажать на клавишу F12 и перейти в вкладку сеть. То-есть есть API которое при открытии из PHP бывает притормаживает, а при открытии из браузера вроде бы на странице этого не наблюдается, получить бы тайминги Curl, возможно это бы прояснило ситуацию. Или может быть такую информацию можно получить при вызове file_get_contents?